# Building matrix with values from multiple files

Tags: python, awk

I have multiple files where i need to create a matrix with matching values

File_1, which is primary file contains all numbers tab delimited with one row

```
  Sample_1   23   45   46   67   78   47   98   73   87   45   97   21
```

There are multiple files where if a number matches, add 1 or else add 0 to file above

File_2

```
Sample_2
23
67
47
235
87
102
97
```

File_3

```
Sample_3
67
51
78
98
52
12
21
124
```

Output

```
Sample_1   23   45   46   67   78   47   98   73   87   45   97   21
Sample_2   1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0
Sample_3   0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Is the order of line 2 onwards in the output file important? If so what determines it?

Comment: order of files line 2,3, etc is not important but order of columns will be standard as they represent positions in a genome which are usually in increasing order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'function pr() {for(i=2;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%d", OFS,(h[i] in p)+0; print ""}     
       NR==1  {n=split($0,h); print; next} 
       FNR==1 {if(f) pr(); delete p; printf "%s",$0} {f=1;p[$1]} 
       END    {pr()}' file1 file2 file3 | column -t

Sample_1  23  45  46  67  78  47  98  73  87  45  97  21
Sample_2  1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
Sample_3  0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: thx. This should work for multiple files, just the first one is treated differently due to structure.

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

With given input, using gawk below one produces required o/p.

**Input:**

```
$ cat f1
Sample_1   23   45   46   67   78   47   98   73   87   45   97   21

$ cat f2
Sample_2
23
67
47
235
87
102
97

Sample_3
67
51
78
98
52
12
21
124
```

**Script:**

```
$ cat t.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v OFS="\t" '
            NR==1{                             
                  $1=$1; total = split($0, arr); print; nextfile
            }
            function print_rec( i){
             if(has_old)
               for(i=2; i in arr; i++)
                  printf("%s%s",(arr[i] in farr ? 1 : 0 ) , (i<total ? OFS:RS) )
            }
            /^Sample_*/{
                   print_rec(); delete farr;
                   printf ("%s%s",$1, OFS); next 
            }
            NF{
                   farr[$1]; has_old=1;   
            }
            END{
                print_rec();
            }' f1 f2
```

***Output:***

```
$ chmod +x t.sh 
$ ./t.sh 
Sample_1    23  45  46  67  78  47  98  73  87  45  97  21
Sample_2    1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
Sample_3    0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked well for me as well as the one above awk solution

Comment: @Empyreanrocks if you want to give multiple files then just replace `/^Sample_*/{` with `FNR==1{`

Comment: thank you for your comment. I have edited my question as i realized after posting that my File_2 has both Sample_2 and Sample_3 together. But i have Sample_2 in File_2 and Sample_3 in File_3. Like that similarly i have more than hundred files to give as input. your solution worked well as i added all the files as input f1 f2 f3 f4 .. can you suggest what to change in the code to make it simpler if i have sample_2 and sample_3 split in different files?

Comment: I already suggested to replace if you are having multiple files, once after replacing you can give input in wildcard like `file1 sample*`

Answer (score 2):

Solution algorithm can be:

- read first file and store data in a hash with sample name as a key and rest as array data
- read second file as records with an empty line as record separator
- split records into sample name and an array of data
- form a hash with the array data entity as a key and assign value 1
- remap data array to 0 or 1 based on element presence in array for Sample_1
- store result in samples hash
- output sample name and data array for each element of samples hash sorted on key

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file_1 = 'sample_1.dat';
my $file_2 = 'samples.dat';
my $samples;

open my $fh, '<', $file_1
    or die "Couldn't open $file_1";
my ($name,@genome) = split(' ', <$fh>);
close $fh;

$samples->{$name} = \@genome;

{
    $/ = "\n\n";

    open $fh, '<', $file_2
        or die "Couldn't open $file_2";
        
    while( my $block = <$fh> ) {
        my($name,@genome) = split(' ', $block);
        my %hash;
        $hash{$_} = 1 for @genome;
        @genome = map{ $hash{$_} ? 1 : 0 } @{$samples->{Sample_1}};
        $samples->{$name} = \@genome;
    }

    close $fh;
}

for my $sample ( sort keys %$samples ) {
    say "$sample " . join("\t",@{$samples->{$sample}}) 
}
```

Output

```
Sample_1 23     45      46      67      78      47      98      73      87      45      97      21
Sample_2 1      0       0       1       0       1       0       0       1       0       1       0
Sample_3 0      0       0       1       1       0       1       0       0       0       0       1
```